# Magento1 submit order process is very slow for customers having 100s of order in account

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

We're observing slow submit order process for few customers who've 1000s of orders in their account. Order submit process take Approximately 2 to 3 Minutes to place order. We're placing order from admin.

Order submit is working fine for other customers, there are only issues with customers who've 1000s of order in their account.

We're using Magento EE version, Archive Sales Order functionality is enabled in system.

Current Magento version is 1.14.3.3

Any Idea what is wrong?

Comment: Turn on Sales flat order

Comment: You can try turn on the mysql slow queries log to analyse if have any query from any module that causes this issue and than, refectory it.